# How would I modify a 3d cave systems so that it is does not remove as much material from the surface?

Tags: java, lwjgl, noise, procedural-generation

Currently I am tackling a project involving 3d noise and the Marching Cubes algorithm to create a 3d procedurally generated world. I already have the code to create the above ground with mountains, cliffs, and overhangs using a mix of 2d and 3d simplex noise. In order to implement the cave system I simply used 3d simplex noise to carve out empty space underneath the main terrain mesh(Since I am using the marching cubes algorithm any vertex that is below the surfaceLevel variable is considered empty space). The main problem that I am having right now is that there are too many caves appearing above ground. One solution I came across [here](http://accidentalnoise.sourceforge.net/minecraftworlds.html) is to somehow make it so that the caves become narrower the closer it is to the surface. However, I have no idea how to implement this. Another solution I came across is from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MazA1SlpwTY) video which was to create a noise mask(Again I have no idea how this works or how to implement it). How would I implement these methods or Is there a better way to make it so that the caves will not remove as much of the surface.

**Current Problem**
[image]

**Current Code**

```
        for(int y = 0; y<height+1; y++){
            for(int x = x1; x<x1+width+1; x++){
                for(int z = z1; z<z1+width+1; z++){ 
                    double noise3d = this.sumOctaves(4,x,y,z,0.5,0.01,0,1); // creates 3d terrain like caves and overhangs
                    double noise2d = this.sumOctaves(4,x,z,0.5,0.01,0,1); // creates 2d terrain like mountains and hills (gives only height)
                    double cave = this.sumOctaves(1,x,y,z,0.5,0.035,0,1); // creates 3d terrain like caves and overhangs
                    double mask =  this.sumOctaves(1,x,z,0.1,0.0019,0,1); // creates a 2d mask to vary heights of regions, lower the scale more diversity in regions, higher the scale more mountains and canyons
                    float curHeight = -y+height/3+(float)height*(float)(noise2d*(1-perlin3Dratio)+noise3d*perlin3Dratio)*(float)mask; // mixing them together with correct ratio of 3d and 2d data
                    if(cave < surfaceLevel){//checks if the noise value is empty space
                        curHeight = (float)cave;
                    }
                    terrainMap[x-x1][y][z-z1] = curHeight;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Apperantly Minecraft caves are not formed with 3d noise. Instead they use Perlin Worms

Comment: Could you approach the problem laterally and accept the surface caves but then "erode" them a bit? Depending on how much erosion you do, you get little valley with sharp edges (recognisable craters or calderas - actually kind of cool in my opinion) or smooth edges (negligible dents). What keeps you from this? I realise that you are following a mathmatical approach instead of detecting caves vs surface. But with a target as strictly "cave-surface-collision" related as the described problem you might not get around processing them more explicitly.

Comment: This might not give you the results you want, but a very simple option to try out is to just not allow caves above a certain y level.